# Join two array for Google Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I want to full join two arrays to plot on the Google Chart line graphic. The X must be the day and the Y the values (values1 and values2)

First array:

```
data1 = [ 'day', 'values1' ],
    [ '01', 6471.92 ],
    [ '02', 14487.97 ],
    [ '03', 28230.21 ],
    [ '04', 46632.87 ],
    [ '05', 58017.5 ],
    [ '06', 65310.17 ],
    [ '07', 71586.54 ],
    [ '08', 79214.96 ],
    [ '09', 85993.71 ],
    [ '10', 98608.51 ],
    [ '11', 115264.9 ],
    [ '12', 123930.66 ],
```

Second array: (exactly the same values)

```
data2 = [ 'day', 'values2' ],
    [ '01', 6471.92 ],
    [ '02', 14487.97 ],
    [ '03', 28230.21 ],
    [ '04', 46632.87 ],
    [ '05', 58017.5 ],
    [ '06', 65310.17 ],
    [ '07', 71586.54 ],
    [ '08', 79214.96 ],
    [ '09', 85993.71 ],
    [ '10', 98608.51 ],
    [ '11', 115264.9 ],
    [ '12', 123930.66 ],
```

Code:

```
var v1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data1);
var v2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data2);
var joinData = new google.visualization.data.join(
  v1,
  v2,
  'full',
  [[0,0]],
  [1],
  [1]
);
```

What i expected was the two lines overlaped, but I got:

[image]

Any ideia?

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see following working snippet.
the lines appear to overlap here.

something doesn't look right with your data.
in the post, don't see the opening and closing brackets on the arrays...?

```
  var data1 = [  // <-- opening bracket
    [ 'day', 'values1' ],
    [ '01', 6471.92 ],
    [ '02', 14487.97 ],
    [ '03', 28230.21 ],
    [ '04', 46632.87 ],
    [ '05', 58017.5 ],
    [ '06', 65310.17 ],
    [ '07', 71586.54 ],
    [ '08', 79214.96 ],
    [ '09', 85993.71 ],
    [ '10', 98608.51 ],
    [ '11', 115264.9 ],
    [ '12', 123930.66 ],
  ];  // <-- closing bracket
```

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data1 = [
    [ 'day', 'values1' ],
    [ '01', 6471.92 ],
    [ '02', 14487.97 ],
    [ '03', 28230.21 ],
    [ '04', 46632.87 ],
    [ '05', 58017.5 ],
    [ '06', 65310.17 ],
    [ '07', 71586.54 ],
    [ '08', 79214.96 ],
    [ '09', 85993.71 ],
    [ '10', 98608.51 ],
    [ '11', 115264.9 ],
    [ '12', 123930.66 ],
  ];

  var data2 = [
    [ 'day', 'values2' ],
    [ '01', 6471.92 ],
    [ '02', 14487.97 ],
    [ '03', 28230.21 ],
    [ '04', 46632.87 ],
    [ '05', 58017.5 ],
    [ '06', 65310.17 ],
    [ '07', 71586.54 ],
    [ '08', 79214.96 ],
    [ '09', 85993.71 ],
    [ '10', 98608.51 ],
    [ '11', 115264.9 ],
    [ '12', 123930.66 ],
  ];

  var v1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data1);
  var v2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data2);
  var joinData = new google.visualization.data.join(
    v1,
    v2,
    'full',
    [[0,0]],
    [1],
    [1]
  );

  var options = {
    legend: {
      position: 'top'
    },
    pointSize: 8
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(joinData, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: HI, I figured out the problem. I had the value '01'  duplicated in one of the arrays. On the code snippet i  paste only part of the array. Best regards

Answer (score 1):

In you're case you can try something like this maybe:

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Values1', 'Values2'],
    ['01', 6471.92, 6471.92],
    ['02', 14487.97, 14487.97],
    ['03', 28230.21, 28230.21],
    ['04', 46632.87, 46632.87]
    ['05', 200, 300]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Company Performance',
    curveType: 'function',
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom'
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

you can look up the example provided for line charts in the docs **[HERE](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart)**